# How to merge several repositories in git

Tags: git, github

I cloned several repositories (coding exercises) into one folder on my machine.
Then I made a repository on github to keep that folder.
But Git won't push my changes to the repository since they belong to other repositories.
Please tell me how can I push all those repositories and my changes into one repo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed, like @Geru told you, delete the `.git` folder in the subdirectories if you don't want to keep the git history of the different directories you aggregate.

If you want to keep the history, you will have to have a look to the `git subtree add -P <NameOfSubDirectory> <commit>` command.

The goal here is for each source repositories, do in the target repository:

1. Add a remote to the source repository
2. git fetch
3. `git subtree add -P <NameOfSubDirectory> <commit>` whith , the sha1 of the last commit you want to take

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the `.git` folder in every of those directories. After that git won't recognize them as directories already checked in to github.

Comment: Why does this answer the question? Unless you’re answering a previous edit, the solution would seem to involve changing the remote. Not complaining deleting the history.

Comment: The way I understood the question was that Charlote just wants to have a quick method with which she could manager her own changes in her test directory. I personally would prefer to have all of these projects as single remote repositories in my own github account, but as far as I understand she's (sorry for assuming a gender) trying to have a simple solution for having them in one project. I thought that submodules or remote repository changes might be a little out of scope for that.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that.